# TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable in trying to make a blackjack game

Tags: python

Currently attempting to make a blackjack game with the code:

```
cards = [11, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10]
while blackjack_start == "y":
  
  #player card and comp card list
  player_cards = [(random.choice(cards)), (random.choice(cards))]
  comp_cards = [(random.choice(cards)), (random.choice(cards))]
  #scores
  player_score = sum(player_cards)
  comp_score = sum(comp_cards)
  print(f"Your Cards: {player_cards[0][1][2][3][4]}, current score: {player_score}  Computer's first card: {comp_cards[0]}")
  hit = input("Type 'y' to get another card, type 'n' to pass: \n")
```

The error occurs on the print statement and says that TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable in trying to make a blackjack game

I tried to convert it into a string but ran into TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Any help from anyone anywhere is greatly appreciated as I am new to this so.

I was trying to assign 2 random scores selected from the list and assign them to player_cards and comp_cards

I was then attempting to print out these said scores to the user, using the scores positions in the given list

Comment: Why is this tagged java and python? Are you unsure what language it is you are programming in?

Comment: What do you expect `{player_cards[0][1][2][3][4]}` do evaluate to?

Comment: I was expecting {player_cards[0][1][2][3][4]} to print out the current cards stored in player_cards[]  since there were only 2 stored at the time I was thinking that It would only print out those first 2

Comment: Nope, that's not what it means. You probably wanted a slice, like `player_cards[:4]`

Comment: Ohh i see, Thank you I really appreciate the help you have given

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when evaluating `player_cards[0][1][2][3][4]` python would first evaluate `player_cards[0]` which is a number (let's suppose it's 4) and then try to do something like `4[1][2][3][4]`, so it tries to interpret `4[1]` which obviously fails because `4` cannot be subscripted, hence the error.

If you want the first at most 5 elements of the array you can use a slice, so

```
{player_cards[0:4]}
```

Which, since we're starting from the beginning of the array, can be abbreviated to

```
{player_cards[:4]}
```